# How to create responsive text inside p tag

Tags: html, css

inside I have text, the p tag is also inside in a div tag, I need the tex to be responsive.

this is my html and css code

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="box4">
                <p><a href="#" class="texto4">Brigadistas</a></p>   
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="box5">
               <p><a href="#" class="texto5">Copasst</a></p>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
         <div id="box6">
             <p><a href="#" class="texto6">Normatividad</a></p> 
          </div>
        </div>  
  </div>


#box4 p a{

   text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 63px;
    left: 57px;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:  white;
}

#box5 p a{

   text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 63px;
    left: 57px;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:  white;
}


#box6 p a {

   text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 63px;
    left: 57px;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:  white;
}
```

the text inside the p tag is outside of the div when the browser resizes.

I used width:100% but nothing happens.

this is a screenshot of my [image: problem]

Comment: responsive how ?

Comment: Adarsh please a little help here.

Comment: You're using absolute sizing and positioning (pixels, px) rather than relative values like %, em, rem, vh, vw etc.  You might find this link useful: http://www.creativebloq.com/rwd/responsive-web-design-tutorials-71410085

Comment: when you use % and pixels , that is bound to happen. Try using all % or all px. I would recommend all %.

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you're placing the text left 57px which is pushing it out of the div. How do you need the text positioned? Does it need 57px always to the left  does it need to be aligned to the right, or can it be aligned fully with the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. thanks! i used %

```
#box4,#box5,#box6{

    width: 60%;
    background:rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
    margin-top:34%;
    padding-top: 34%;
    margin-bottom: 14%;
    position: relative;
    left:24%;
    border-radius:12%;  
    border:5px solid rgb(178,205,73);
}

#box4 p a{

    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 33%;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 140%;
    color:  white;

}

#box5 p a{

   text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 33%;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 140%;
    color:  white;

}


#box6 p a {

  text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 33%;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 140%;
    color:  white;
```

Answer (score 0):

If using flex just make it : `justify-content: center` make sure the parent is flex. In this case no need to use positions.